# How to not navigate to other app from my web view?

Tags: android, webview

I am updating my app Before my app was having a separate native chat option and when link are shared the app used to open it in our webview itself now We have directed it to our new website which is loading in a webview of our app.Problem is when users are clicking any links its either going to Native browser or it is getting opened in native apps.Like if there is a link of quora being shared when link is clicked it is redirecting it to quora app.How to solve this problem.Users are complaining about this.We are loosing our customers please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `WebView` tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview). Just implement the web client and set it before loadUrl. The simplest way is:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

now the user will not leave the app , and navigation will keep going on your webview